# merging two var in jQuery selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to get two selected values from a dropdown list using jQuery and able to retrieve those successfully.The problem is im unable to merge the content retrieved. Follwing is the code.

```
    var selectedTemplate;

    var selectedAssignment;

    var mergeValue;

    var divContent = "<div id='" + criterion.id + "' customId='" + mergeValue + "'                style='font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;'>" + criterion.expression + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                  "<a href='#' onclick=\"removeCriterion('" + criterion.id +
                  "')\"><spring:message code="form.text.criteria.remove"/></a></div>\n";


selectedTemplate   = $("#criteriaTemplate option:selected").val(); // 1st dropdown value
selectedAssignment = $("#criteriaOptions option:selected" ).val(); // 2nd dropdown value

alert("this is the Assignment value in add block: " + selectedAssignment); // success
alert("This should be the template in add block: "  + selectedTemplate);   // success

 //mergeValue = $(selectedTemplate,selectedAssignment);
 mergeValue = selectedTemplate.add(selectedAssignment); // unable able to merge the content

 alert("This is the value of the merge content in the add block: "+mergeValue); // alert is also not generated
```

and i am trying to append the merge content to customID in a  block but in the browser when i check it is showing as follows

```
<div id="8a808088442eb48001442efe70f20010" customid="undefined" style="font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">some Text here &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="removeCriterion('8a808088442eb48001442efe70f20010')">Remove</a></div>
```

suggest me some solution

Comment: any error in you console

Comment: what do you mean by merging? do you mean concatenate

Comment: You cannot use `.add()` on strings.

Comment: Are you trying to collect both values together in an array?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that jQuery can retrieve the value of a `select` element even more [succinctly](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1): `var selectedTemplate = $('#criteriaTemplate').val();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to concatenate both values to one String, use the `+`operator:

```
mergeValue = selectedTemplate + selectedAssignement;
```

Result would be:

```
mergeValue = "SomeTemplateSomeAssignement"
```

---

If you want to have both of them in one array, just assign them to an array:

```
mergeValue = [selectedTemplate, selectedAssignement]
```

Or

```
mergeValue = [];
mergeValue.push(selectedTemplate);
mergeValue.push(selectedAssignement);
```

Result would be:

```
mergeValue = [
    "SomeTemplate",
    "SomeAssignement"
]
```

Comment: Sorry @MichaelZalla, overwrote your edit. Fixed the typos anyway, but thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Hi Johannes H ,when i append this merge content to the customId in the div on the fly, i was getting customId="undefined" in browser.

Comment: @user3214740 Hm. Mind to show us all the code you got now? If mergeValue is undefinied, there sure is a reason for it ;)

Comment: merge content is="com.certification.impl.DueDateTemplate8"

Comment: Best to poast a new question on this, with the full code. It's clearly another issue. YOu can give me the link if you want me to look into it.

Comment: Hi Johannes H this is the url of new issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/21772640/3214740

Answer (score 3):

You need to use concatenation as `selectedTemplate` and `selectedAssignment` values of the jQuery object I think what you are looking for is to concatenate them

```
mergeValue = selectedTemplate + selectedAssignment;
```

---

```
var selectedTemplate;

var selectedAssignment;

selectedTemplate = $("#criteriaTemplate option:selected").val(); // 1st dropdown value
selectedAssignment = $("#criteriaOptions option:selected").val(); // 2nd dropdown value

var mergeValue = selectedTemplate + selectedAssignment;

var divContent = "<div id='" + criterion.id + "' customId='" + mergeValue + "'                style='font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;'>" + criterion.expression + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
    "<a href='#' onclick=\"removeCriterion('" + criterion.id +
    "')\"><spring:message code="
form.text.criteria.remove "/></a></div>\n";


alert("this is the Assignment value in add block: " + selectedAssignment); // success
alert("This should be the template in add block: " + selectedTemplate); // success

alert("Merged: " + mergeValue);
```

Comment: I'm curious, why the downvotes? As `.val()`returns strings, this answer looks quite OK to me...

Comment: Why was this down voted? The question is unclear not this answer.

Comment: @ArunPJohny ANd you won'T loose them, votes are fixed after 10 minutes (unlesss you edit). I doubt that the downvoters are reading this topic anyway.

Comment: Hi Arun P Johny ,when i append this merge content to the customId in the div on the fly, i was getting customId="undefined" in browser.

Comment: @user3214740 execution order of the code is not proper

Comment: Hi Arun P Johny this is the url of new issue stackoverflow.com/q/21772640/3214740