# Unable to append concatenated value to a customId in a div block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is im unable to add the merged content to the div block for a customId. Follwing is the code.

```
     var selectedTemplate;

        var selectedAssignment;

        var mergeValue;

        var divContent = "<div id='" + criterion.id + "' customId='" + mergeValue + "'                style='font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;'>" + criterion.expression + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                      </div>\n";


    selectedTemplate   = $("#criteriaTemplate option:selected").val(); // 1st dropdown value
    selectedAssignment = $("#criteriaOptions option:selected" ).val(); // 2nd dropdown value

     mergeValue = selectedTemplate + selectedAssignment;
```

and i am trying to append the merge content to customID in a  block but in the browser when i check `InspectElement` it is showing as follows

```
    <div id="8a808088442eb48001442efe70f20010" customid="undefined" style="font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">some Text here &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
```

suggest me some solution

Comment: Did you assign value to mergeValue?.

Comment: Due to javascript closure properties you need to set value to the mergeValue before concatenating.

Comment: @AdeshPandey I don'T see no closure in there...

Comment: @JohannesH. thanks for correcting me. Its not because of closures its hoisting because variable has declared before being used and its values are assigned later.

Comment: @AdeshPandey not even that, it's fine to declare varaibles after usage, variable declaration are always processed before code (in Javascript that is!). YOu ustr have to set the value first. `function test() {foo="bar"; alert(foo); alert(window.foo); var foo;}` is fine, it will set the local variable, not `window.foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the assignment **mergeValue = selectedTemplate + selectedAssignment;**   before using the variable.

The complete code is:

```
    var selectedTemplate;            
    var selectedAssignment;            
    var mergeValue;                     

    selectedTemplate   = $("#criteriaTemplate option:selected").val(); // 1st dropdown value
    selectedAssignment = $("#criteriaOptions option:selected" ).val(); 

    mergeValue = selectedTemplate + selectedAssignment;      

    var divContent = "<div id='" + criterion.id + "' customId='" + mergeValue + "'                style='font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;'>" + criterion.expression + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                              </div>\n";
```

Comment: I think mergeValue value will be NaN always. Two undefined varaible you trying to add it will give NaN.

Comment: @Raja Jaganathan Thanks thats a typo, fixed the code

Answer (score 2):

You are using the merged variable(`mergeValue`) before its value is set, so use

```
var selectedTemplate = $("#criteriaTemplate option:selected").val(); // 1st dropdown value
var selectedAssignment = $("#criteriaOptions option:selected").val(); // 2nd dropdown value

var mergeValue = selectedTemplate + selectedAssignment;

var divContent = "<div id='" + criterion.id + "' customId='" + mergeValue + "'                style='font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;'>" + criterion.expression + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
    "<a href='#' onclick=\"removeCriterion('" + criterion.id +
    "')\"><spring:message code="
form.text.criteria.remove "/></a></div>\n";


alert("this is the Assignment value in add block: " + selectedAssignment); // success
alert("This should be the template in add block: " + selectedTemplate); // success

alert("Merged: " + mergeValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to set value for `mergeValue` before construct div.

```
    var selectedTemplate;

    var selectedAssignment;

    var mergeValue;

    selectedTemplate   = $("#criteriaTemplate option:selected").val(); // 1st dropdown value
    selectedAssignment = $("#criteriaOptions option:selected" ).val(); // 2nd dropdown value

     mergeValue = selectedTemplate + selectedAssignment;

var divContent = "<div id='" + criterion.id + "' customId='" + mergeValue + "'                style='font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;'>" + criterion.expression + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                      </div>\n";
```

Comment: Always use the "var" keyword, unless you reall want to add properties to `window`! (I know you just skipped the lines, but that only leads to errors from people who don't realize it)

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedTemplate;   
var selectedAssignment;    
var mergeValue; 




selectedTemplate   = $("#criteriaTemplate option:selected").val(); // 1st dropdown value
selectedAssignment = $("#criteriaOptions option:selected" ).val(); // 2nd dropdown value

 mergeValue = selectedTemplate + selectedAssignment;

var divContent = "<div id='" + criterion.id + "' customId='" + mergeValue + "'                style='font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;'>" + criterion.expression + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                  </div>\n";
```

I think this should work. In your code you are using mergeValue before assignment. That is why it is undefined.